# Will elementary OS work on the Asus tinkerboard?

Tags: system-installation

I am making at school a arcade machine where the game is an accelerated reader test. I am looking for a single board computer that will support Elementary OS.

My school is a Windows School, and I would like an example of linux so the students know what linux is. I think linux very powerful and I want to do this in a way so more people can meet linux.

Answer (score 1):

**TL; DR Not for now.**

As far as I know, the Tinkerboard is an ARM-based computer whereas elementary OS 0.4 loki only supports amd64 and 0.3 freya i386 or amd64. However, there are plans to port it to arm as well. So a future version, maybe…